# Creating legend from label classes or annotations in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling, annotation

I have a single "geonames" layer with 56 label classes and another few layers with around 10 label classes. Each class has a different font and colour or graphic. I would like to add most of these labels along a regular symbol in my legend.  I am building my legends by converting them to graphics but it would still be nice to not to have to create a representative label for each label class manually.  In case of symbology I simply make a legend, tweak the font and size of the symbols, export and work with the static graphics. **I am wondering if anyone has a script or a procedure that can make a dump of all the label symbols, each a representative of each class.**  (I believe this could be obtained programmatically since ArcMap is already doing it - Labels Tab -> Expression -> Verify -> resulting Expression Verification shows a sample label graphic.) I would like to somehow spit out this same graphic along with the label class name onto the map layout.

Programmatic VB.NET / ArcObjects solution showing how retrieve the label class name and it's symbol and would be acceptable.

I found [Placing label designs in legend of ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4829) asking a very similar question about version 9.3 and although marked as answered it doesn't really provide a satisfactory solution. I am using 10.2.2

Figure 1: ArcMap Label Expression Verification showing that it already generates the graphic:
[image]

Figure 2:  A example I made manually showing what I would like to get from a layer with 4 label classes:
[image]

Comment: I've a similar problem [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/how-to-add-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap). Did you finally found any solution?