# Adding labels with symbols to legend in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, symbology, legend

I'm creating a map with **ArcGIS Desktop v10.2.2**, showing museums as points. The museums layer **has no symbol** and the labels are made of a circle filled with color with the ID inside, taken from the `[ID]` field.

I want to add the entire list of museums in the layout map legend, having a list of my symbols with their IDs and the description (their name) taken from the `[LABEL]` field, without creating it manually.

I know that a possible manual solution would be to set the layer symbology to "Unique values", then add all values (more than 100!) and set once for each point the same label symbology. But I hope there's a better solution!

Take a look at my map below.

The layer is "Musei" (Museums) and as you can see on the legend on the left, it has no symbol. On the right you can see the descripted legend symbology, a Dark gray circle with Red text inside taken from the `[ID]` field. **I want to add to my layout a column containing all the circles with IDs and the corresponding label.**

[image: Museums]

**-- UPDATE --**

This is the Field Calculator settings I used following the solution proposed by @FelixIP.

[image: Field Calculator]

But the points are not positioned in vertical align as I expect. Instead they're moved a bit here and there. I also tried using different step values: 10, 100, 1000, 10000.

Comment: Could you insert a table next to your legend?

Comment: @whatahitson Do you mean a table frame in the layout view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get this:

[image]

I've used 2 dataframes:

[image]

STEPS:

a) Create a copy of your museums shapefile; b)Note xMean, yMax of the points
and c) Run this field calculator expression multiple times changing **step** on Shape field until you happy with interval between vertical points

```
def vertical(fid, shp,xMean,yMax,step):
 y=yMax-step*fid
 pNew=arcpy.Point(xMean,y)
 return pNew
```

Using

```
vertical( !FID!, !Shape!, 1563910,5177655,100)
```

It will create vertical chain of your points to be displayed and labelled in 2nd dataframe === legend

Update: average longitude of the points i used is 1563910, maximum latitude 5177655

Comment: I'm trying but maybe I didn't understand correctly your procedure.
I've already have the X and Y coordinates of the points in two fields of the museums table. Do I need to calculate a new X and Y position in a new field? I used Field Calculatore putting on it your function definition followed by the function call but I get a 999999 undefined error and "missing istruction end" message.

Comment: No new fields. Run calculator on SHAPE field of the backup copy. If you don't understand what function does, simply draw vertical line in your view and snap points to it, fid=0 on the top, fid=1 below etc

Comment: I tried you solution, please take a look at my question update.

Comment: You are not reading my solution carefully. When you call expression, you must use SINGLE numerics fo 3rd and 4th parameter, not coordinates of indiv.points stored in fields. If you have 3 points with x-s 1,2,3  your 3rd parameter has t be 2. Take a pen and write down AVEARAGE longitude and MAXIMUM latitude of your points

Comment: Alternatively, export the rows from the shapefile you are trying to label, pull them into excel, add x,y points for a series of vertically distributed points, (1,9; 1,8; 1,7, etc.), and put it into the additional dataframe with "Add X,Y data." Also make sure that the label placement for your two label shapefiles are set appropriately - i.e., one is "Top Right ONLY" and the other is "Top Left ONLY."

Comment: @Carolyn Yes this is an option as well. However absence of projection in 2nd dataframe can cause trouble. ArcGIS doesn't like datasets with undefined projection. This is why I am suggesting to put them on vertical line in already defined projection. Thanks for helping me explaining this basic geometric concept