# Dynamic Symbols

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, dynamic

Is there a dynamic symbol (preferably a numbered circle or square) in ArcMap that is symbolized uniquely to each feature?  For example, I have 150 features that I would like to symbolize with a circle and the number 1 - 150 in the center.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by going to the Labels section within Layer Properties, choose Symbol, then Edit Symbol. In the editor go to the Advanced Text tab, and choose Text Background. Click Properties and then choose Marker Text Background from the type drop down. Check the scale marker to fit text box, and choose a symbol from the Symbol... option, a circle for instance.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Now is there a way to create a legend with the newly created labels associated to each feature?

Comment: Please mark this as answered.  There is no way to create a dynamic legend from labels in ArcMap. You will need to build a static legend or you will need to create 150 symbols in symbology categories then create the legend.

Comment: You can create such 'legend'. Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap/170763#170763

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. 
You need to label the feature class. 
Here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RU6kxi-q_oA