# QGIS - Labeling points with numbers and adding text label to legend as list to represent what the numbers are

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am new to GIS and therefore have very limited knowledge of this software.

I have a list of reserves that have been put into the system. To label these I was wondering if there is a way of making the labels into numbers and then beside the map a key of what the numbers represent.

Comment: What system is that a database?

Comment: ArcGIS solution here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to create a data layer with few different data sets associate to it.If I were you, I would create a new vector point layer and generate data fields from the new layer's data table, key, name, numbers etc. This new layer would be representative to the current map you have, select on this layer and "label all" to the fields you want to show on the map from your newly created layer.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Layer properties / Style and select categorized there you can set all of this up