# Point Map Automation with Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I need to create a map book for a large point dataset. The end user wants all points on each page numbered 1 through N and have each number correspond to a table in the layout showing one field from the attribute table. The number of points in each extent ranges from 1 to 300+ in some cases. Ideally this would be an automated process so that when I update data in the future, I can simply export and deliver a new set of maps.

So far, the only option I have found is using the Production Mapping toolbar which I don't have access to. I could get a brief trial but that would end and leave me out to dry for future map iterations. Are there any tools or processes I'm missing that can be used for this?

Comment: I use second dataframes, where cloned copy of original shown with labels. Replace original geometries with ones sitting on vertical line, use page definition query on them and non true type font to label. Greatly doubt though that you can place more than 50 rows 'table'.

Comment: Python. It will be difficult to get 300+ rows into a layout table unless printing large format. If you can place the table on a separate page then you can use core  data driven pages for the layout and python voodoo to make the pdf of the table records

Comment: Your requirements have much in common with the application I build during eLearning course titled [Challenging times with Python and ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro](https://www.udemy.com/challenging-times-with-python-and-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro/) at Udemy - although that is for Pro rather than Desktop.

Comment: @FelixIP'S idea of moving geometries in cloned feature class to vertical line is a good one.

Comment: @PolyGeo See this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap/170763#170763

Comment: So, join points with pages, use https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154 to compute sequential number and solution from above comment. Saved me weeks of work...

Comment: @FelixIP I think this will work well if, like you said, I can get all the records in the densest extent to fit. I might be able to use a 3rd or 4th data frame side by side with multiple definition queries to only show certain ranges in each one.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'll take a look at that. I'm not opposed to using Pro if it will do the job.