# Generating Mapbook with Dynamic Text based on Attributes from Related Table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, data-driven-pages, relates, dynamic-text

I have a series of individual parcels with multiple soil sample points on each parcel. I need a way to communicate the soil sample information to the landowners. There are about 500 parcels so I need a way to automate the creation of maps and a report of the soil analysis, which is in a series of related tables (Site data --> Soil Horizon Info --> Horizon Analytical Results).

One of my solutions is to flatten these tables into a database row for each point, do a spatial join and append the soil point data to the parcel polygon, but this is very time consuming to manually transpose these related records in Excel.

Is there a faster way to use data driven pages and dynamic text on the map layout displaying related data?

[image]

Comment: Can you present soil info as fields in points table?

Comment: Writing dynamic tables for map automation is covered in one of my eLearning courses at https://www.udemy.com/challenging-times-with-python-and-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro/  That course is for ArcGIS Pro but the learnings from it could be back-applied to ArcMap.  The key technique is generating "table-like feature classes" that can be placed in a separate map/data frame on the layout used by cursoring through an index feature class.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'd like a fix that doesn't involve the payment of a time-consuming online course. Thanks.

Comment: @PolyGeo can you be a little more specific in what you mean by "table-like feature classes" and putting it in a separate data frame and cursing through an index feature class? Aren't all feature classes tables as well? How would your suggestion allow me to show information on the map layout based on related tables to the soil point feature class?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap

Comment: @ATomz By table-like feature class I mean a polygon feature class of rectangles that look like the cells of a table plus a "header row".

Comment: @ATomz if you can get your data into a table then that table can be displayed as a table-like feature class. The coding patterns are non-trivial but extremely flexible which is why it takes a short course to explain them in detail.

Comment: @FelixIP that post of yours uses a similar idea and looking at its date was around when I did the work that led to my course. Consequently, it may have been something that contributed to the way I do dynamic tables.