# Data Driven Pages: Show sum of attributes organized by type per page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

I am using Data Driven Pages to symbolize several types of road classes within several municipal areas. The municipal areas themselves are my index. I am also using a definition query on the road class data to only show the particular segments within each area (page).

Within my legend, I would like to figure out how to display the total length of all road segments broken down by road class and to update accordingly with the point of interest as I navigate through the pages.

Example: Page 1: Arterials - 45.321kms/ Page 2: Arterials - 83.670kms ETC.

Is this type of dynamic text feasible?

Comment: Dissolve roads by page id and road types. Convert their table to points. Create overlapping points using technique https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap and second dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer page IDs to roads table, dissolve by 2 attributes to multipart lines and compute their lengths:

[image]

Derive single point per multipart line. I used Feature to Point tool to do so:

[image]

The trick is placing these point in the second data frame which will work as a legend. So compute coordinates of points and their [sequential number](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154) on the page. Populate POINT_X by mean of Xs, populate POINT_Y by yMax-step*GRP_NUMBER (note I used 500 instead of step):

[image]

Place points under each other on a vertical line using:

```
arcpy.Point( !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!)
```

on field Shape.

Place modified points in second dataframe, label them and enable page definition:

[image]

You can play with labels (monospace fonts!) to create dynamic table.

Alternative: is [Production Mapping](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/what-is-production-mapping.htm). I've heard it does exactly this.