# Listing numbered properties in legend using numbered symbols in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, legend, numbering

I am trying to create a legend for properties that are identified on the map with numbers. I'd like the legend symbol to be a yellow circle with the property number inside, with the name of the property to the right of the numbered circle. The properties should be listed in ascending numerical order. I am using ArcMap 10.8.2 (Desktop).

I've created a point layer for the symbols, and for symbology I selected Unique Values and [NAME] for value field. Within the Table of Contents, I changed each individual symbol to a yellow circle.

I selected IDNumber for the feature label. This results in numbered circles in the appropriate locations on the map itself. However, when I try to create a legend for it with the property names as described in the previous paragraph, each property in the list is preceded by a blank symbol, and the properties are in alphabetical order instead of numeric order.

A sample map is attached showing the legend with blank yellow circles.

I tried editing the symbol itself to include text by adding a layer but cannot add more than a single digit (I cannot find any fonts that include numbers greater than 9).  The text in other symbols in Symbol Selector cannot be edited.

I looked at the answer/solution posted by Felix P./PolyGeo. Why are field calculations and data frames used for the solution? I am not very experienced here, and as of now, I do not understand the solution proposed.

My last resort is to create symbols with text inside of them in another application, create a text box with the desired information, and add it to the layout, but hope there is a solution within ArcMap!

[image: Sample map in question]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap#170763

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by *manually* updating the symbols adding marker layers to your symbology. Its a faff but would achieve what you want.  Firstly don't turn on labels, create your unique symbol rendered and make them all the yellow circles you want, then for each individual *unique* symbol adjust it as you want (i.e. add the number you want to see).  Below is a short video I made for you to understand how to alter symbols with additional layers. I had to make to b&w to get it small enough to upload.

You need to do it this way as ArcMap has no capability to link the symbol design to an attribute value.

[image: Adding character markers to symbols]

Comment: Sorry @BERA for slow response! I have used the excellent [screentogif](https://www.screentogif.com/) Windows app

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is to use the description field and give the text an offset to place the description over the symbol.
[image][image]